# How to deserialize data at client side when web api action return data in xml format

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asp.net-web-api

1) first situation is say my web api action return data in xml format. so tell me when i will call that web api action with httpclient then how could i deserialize that customer xml data to my customer class at client side ?

### suppose this is my web api actions

```
   [RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly ICustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();

        [HttpGet, Route("GetAll")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAllCustomers()
        {
            //return new Response(true, "SUCCESS", repository.GetAll());
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Response(true, "SUCCESS", repository.GetAll()));
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetByID/{customerID}")]
        public Response GetCustomer(string customerID)
        {
            Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return new Response(true, "SUCCESS", customer);
            //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetByCountryName/{country}")]
        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountry(string country)
        {
            return repository.GetAll().Where(
                c => string.Equals(c.Country, country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            customer = repository.Add(customer);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = customer.CustomerID });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }

        public void PutProduct(string customerID, Customer customer)
        {
            customer.CustomerID = customerID;
            if (!repository.Update(customer))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteProduct(string customerID)
        {
            Customer customer = repository.Get(customerID);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            repository.Remove(customerID);
        }
    }

public class Response
    {
        bool IsSuccess = false;
        string Message;
        object ResponseData;

        public Response(bool status, string message, object data)
        {
            IsSuccess = status;
            Message = message;
            ResponseData = data;
        }
    }

   public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
    }
```

### now calling like this way

```
    var baseAddress = "http://localhost:8010/api/customer/GetAll";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(baseAddress))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

when `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is true then tell me how could i read the response and extract the customer data from response class.

just give me sample code of `HttpClient` which show me how to `deserialize` response and customer class. please include sample code which i can use.

just give me sample client code which show me how to hold xml from response and deserialize it to customer class. thanks

Comment: [Use XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Something like this you mean?

```
var baseAddress = "http://localhost:8010/api/customer/GetAll";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(baseAddress))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
              using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
              {
                  string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                  var newCustomer = (customer)serializer.Deserialize(result);
              }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```